# What is the standard data-structure to get Http client request in Http Web Server project

Tags: sockets, http, webserver, buffer, inputstream

I am writing **HTTP WEB SERVER**. In that code, I used **byte array** to get the client request, and then process, but that have performance issue, when I call different RequestHandler , i.e., `Get`, `Head` and other.

**My current code is,**

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(client_socket.getInputStream());
PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(client_socket.getOutputStream());

try {
     buffer_request_size = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);

     if (buffer[0] == (byte) 'G'  && buffer[1] == (byte) 'E' && buffer[2] == (byte) 'T' && buffer[3] == (byte) ' ') {
            // CALL GETREQUESTHANDLER TO PROCESS CLIENT REQUEST
     }
     else if(buffer[0] == (byte) 'H' && buffer[1] == (byte) 'E' && buffer[2] == (byte) 'A' && buffer[3] == (byte) 'D' && buffer[4] == (byte) ' ') {
            // CALL HEADREQUESTHANDLER TO PROCESS CLIENT REQUEST
     }
     // SIMILARLY PROCESS OTHER HTTP METHODS IN THE SAME WAY
}
finally {
     inputStream.close();
     printStream.close();
}
```

But that is not good coding skill, to check first three character one by one to see if it is `GET` or not.

Is there any other data-structure that **reads** client request, and check first word and tells wheather this GET,or HEAD , or any other?

Please help me in improving above code block.

Comment: Split the buffer into an array of strings at whitespace boundaries, then use string comparison. Use a dispatch table that maps request names to handler functions.

Comment: If you don't understand what I just said, writing an HTTP server may be too advanced a project for you at this stage of your career.

Comment: @barmar I wrote the whole code. But I used the very basic steps. So thats why I want to make my code good from professional point of view.

Comment: @Barmar This is also not a write approach that you said in first coment, I want to ask is there any library to handle client request ?

Comment: I don't know if there are any libraries for this, since it's not common to implement your own HTTP server. If someone needs a web server, they usually adapt one of the open source projects rather than write their own.

Comment: @Barmar Ohk, But I am a student, and I try to implement my own so that I learn the implementation of any project. That's why I am doing this task.

Comment: OK, then see my earlier comment: The standard data structure for this is a dispatch table.